# Pygame displays black window

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing tutorial for platform game but my Pygame window displays a black screen.

I don't know how to solve this.

I tried closing and opening Visual Studio Code again but nothing happens.

```py
import pygame

SCREEN_SIZE = (700,500)
DARK_GREY = (50,50,50)
OGURKOWY = (21,179, 58)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Platformówka")
player_image = pygame.image.load("ogurek\doggo.png")
player_x = 300
platforms = [
  pygame.Rect(100,300,400,50),
  pygame.Rect(100,250 ,50,50),
  pygame.Rect(450,250,50,50),
  pygame.Rect(450,250,100,50)
]

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x += 2   
    #tło
    screen.fill(DARK_GREY)
    #platformy

for p in platforms: 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (OGURKOWY), p)
    #gracz
    screen.blit(player_image, (player_x,100))
    # 
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Your `for` loop that displays the platforms is never called, because it is not inside the `while running` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The `for`-loop that draws the platforms (`for p in platforms:`) must be **in* the application loop instead of **after** the application loop:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x += 2   
    #tło
    screen.fill(DARK_GREY)
    #platformy

# INDENTATION
#-->|
    for p in platforms: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (OGURKOWY), p)
        
    #gracz
    screen.blit(player_image, (player_x,100))
    # 
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

How to fix this apparent indentation issue was [commented by Ari Cooper-Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849051/pygame-displays-black-window/68849437#comment121676132_68849051) and [answered by Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68867290/5730279).

My answer aims to avoid such issues by design (keeping loops short and segregating nested constructs into methods).

---

Advice to avoid such **indentation typos** and improve readability of your code:

- keep the game-loop (your `while running:`) short
- extract code-blocks into functions/methods
- put empty-lines (vertical spacing) between major code-blocks like `for`/`if`/functions, etc.

#### Extract methods

This recipe follows [*Single Responsibility Principle* (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and structures your code like your comments did. Moreover it makes the code more expressive, because method-calls will document same as comments to the reader.

```py
def handle_exit_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


def handle_key_events():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_x += 2   


def draw_background():
    # tło
    screen.fill(DARK_GREY)


def draw_platforms():
    # platformy
    for p in platforms: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (OGURKOWY), p)


def draw_player():
    # gracz
    screen.blit(player_image, (player_x,100))


def update_display():
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Note the 2 blank lines between each method definition.

#### Keep loops short

Now that we declared the methods (before), we can use them to shorten the loop:

```py
# methods declared (from above)

# inits (screen/game-objects/color definitions) omitted to focus on game-loop

running = True
while running:
    handle_exit_events()
    handle_key_events()
    draw_background()  # currently static, could move above loop 
    draw_platforms()  # currently static, could move above loop
    draw_player()  # player move triggered by key-press only
    update_display()

pygame.quit()
```

See how your original comments inside the game-loop (`# platformy`, `# tło` and `# gracz`) were transformed to method-calls. Thus your code documents itself (making these comments obsolete).

### What depends on change inside game-loop ?

Now we can think and recognize dependencies inside the loop.
The game-loop is for interactive parts like reacting to events or updating the screen.

#### Draw static objects once ahead

So the `handle_x_events` methods fit well inside the loop. But some static scenery like *background* and *platforms* are fixed objects in your game. They can be drawn once before entering the game-loop. Because they don't change with any of the events (like quit or key-pressed).

```py
# methods declared (from above)

# inits (screen/game-objects/color definitions) omitted to focus on game-loop
draw_background()
draw_platforms()

running = True
while running:
```

Next is more questionable and depends on your design-approach.

#### Draw player when event triggers change (position or appearence)

`draw_player()` is needed once before the loop because when the game starts, the player is placed into the world. Then the player uses key-presses to change its position (see `handle_key_events()`)   which will trigger the player-image to be re-positioned (horizontally only, `player_x`) and drawn on the screen.

You could express that dependency in code:

```
player_y = 100  # initial vertical position (fixed at the moment)
player_x = 300
player_x_speed = 2  # pixels delta per horizontal movement

def move_player_forward():
    player_x += player_x_speed
    screen.blit(player_image, (player_x, player_y))


def move_player_backward():
    player_x -= player_x_speed
    screen.blit(player_image, (player_x, player_y))


def handle_key_events():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        move_player_backward()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        move_player_forward()

# remaining code

while running:
    handle_exit_events()
    handle_key_events()
    update_display()

pygame.quit()
```

See how the horizontal movement is expressed in code. The `player_x` modification was internalized into the movement methods.

Usually you would work with [`Player` class and objects](https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/#players) or at least player-coordinates, for example defined as [tuple](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/moving-a-rover-and-receiving-current-coordinates), which has some benefits:

```py
player_position = (300, 100)  # pixel coordinates of players initial position`
player_x_speed = 2  # pixels delta per horizontal movement
player_jump_height = 10  # pixels to jump vertically, e.g. on a platform

# walk forward
player_position[0] += player_x_speed

# jump forward
player_position = (player_position[0] + player_x_speed, player_position[1] + player_jump_height)

# directly drawn
screen.blit(player_image, player_position)
```

Comment: how exactly does this answer the question? also python doesn't have such a feature like hoisting, so how do you expect this to not throw errors?

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for your concerns. (a) What is exactly the question? "displays blackscreen i dont know what should i do" - I answered "what to do": how to fix, plus how to avoid. (b) You're right: unlike [JavaScript's _hoisting_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in Python methods should be __declared before__ they're used. So I fix this. Thanks!